# Register generic type

Tags: c#, generics, dependency-injection, autofac

Let's say I have this class:

```
public class DetailedQueryHandler<T> : IQueryHandlerAsync<Detailed, T> 
    where T : CalculationQuery
```

I can register it that way:

```
builder.RegisterType(typeof(DetailedQueryHandler<CalculationWithDealerQuery>))
       .As(typeof(IQueryHandlerAsync<Detailed, CalculationWithDealerQuery>));
builder.RegisterType(typeof(DetailedQueryHandler<CalculationQuery>))
       .As(typeof(IQueryHandlerAsync<Detailed, CalculationQuery>));
```

But I would like to register it in more automatized way, like I can register types to IQueryHandlerAsync interface below:

```
var types = ThisAssembly.GetTypes();
builder.RegisterTypes(types)
       .Where(t => t.ImplementGenericInterface(t2 => t2 == typeof(IQueryHandlerAsync<,>))
       .AsImplementedInterfaces()
```

and

```
public interface IQueryHandlerAsync<T, in TI>

public static bool ImplementGenericInterface(this Type type, Func<Type, bool> comparer) {
        return type.GetInterfaces().Any(i => i.IsGenericType 
            && comparer(i.GetGenericTypeDefinition()));
}
```

What would be a good way to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your code you need a way to associate a specific `IQueryHandlerAsync` implementation to a specific `CalculationQuery`.

One possible way to do this is to register the type you want and create a `AsQueryHandler` method to do the registration for you :

```
public static class ContainerBuilderExtensions
{
    public static IRegistrationBuilder<TLimit, TConcreteActivatorData, SingleRegistrationStyle> AsQueryHandler<TLimit, TConcreteActivatorData>(this IRegistrationBuilder<TLimit, TConcreteActivatorData, SingleRegistrationStyle> registration)
        where TConcreteActivatorData : IConcreteActivatorData

    {
        Type queryHandlerType = registration.ActivatorData.Activator.LimitType;
        Type queryHandlerRegistrationType = queryHandlerType.GetInterfaces().FirstOrDefault(i => i.IsGenericType && i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IQueryHandlerAsync<,>));
        if (queryHandlerRegistrationType == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException($"{queryHandlerType} doesn't implement {typeof(IQueryHandlerAsync<,>).Name} interface");
        }
        TypedService queryHandlerService = new TypedService(queryHandlerRegistrationType);

        return registration.As(queryHandlerService);
    }
}
```

And you would use it like this :

```
builder.RegisterType<DetailedQueryHandler<CalculationQuery>>()
       .AsQueryHandler();
```

If you don't want to manually register all types, you will have to do assembly scanning to compose type you want based on your needs.

Another way to consider is to implement the `IRegistrationSource` interface. This interface contains a `RegistrationsFor` method that will be called when *Autofac* needs a new component. You can see this interface as a way to dynamically register components on demands.

```
public class QueryHandlerRegistrationSource : IRegistrationSource
{
    public Boolean IsAdapterForIndividualComponents
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<IComponentRegistration> RegistrationsFor(Service service, Func<Service, IEnumerable<IComponentRegistration>> registrationAccessor)
    {
        Type serviceType = (service as IServiceWithType)?.ServiceType;

        if (serviceType == null)
        {
            yield break;
        }
        if (serviceType.IsGenericType && serviceType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IQueryHandlerAsync<,>))
        {
            Type[] argumentTypes = serviceType.GetGenericArguments();
            Type t0 = argumentTypes[0];
            Type t1 = argumentTypes[1];

            if (t0 == typeof(Detailed))
            {
                IComponentRegistration registration = RegistrationBuilder.ForType(typeof(DetailedQueryHandler<>).MakeGenericType(t1))
                                                                         .As(service)
                                                                         .CreateRegistration();
                yield return registration;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new NotSupportedException();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Don't forget to register the registration source :

```
builder.RegisterSource(new QueryHandlerRegistrationSource());
```

Instead of the `if (t0 == typeof(Detailed))` you can use a `IDictionary<Type, Type>` as a parameter of the `QueryHandlerRegistrationSource`.